# How to sort contacts alphabetically in Skype for Business

Tags: microsoft-office, skype, sorting, skype-for-business

I am using *Skype for Business*.
[image]

I observed that the list of contacts is sorted alphabetically, but by first name for some people and by family name for others, e.g.:

> Albert Einstein
>
> Doe, John
>
> Max Planck

It would make more sense to sort them all by either first name or by family name:

> Albert Einstein
>
> John Doe
>
> Max Planck

or

> Doe, John
>
> Einstein, Albert
>
> Planck, Max

What is the cause of this strange behaviour and how can I solve it?

UPDATE

It seems that most contacts are sorted by their family name by default. If a contact is sorted by its first name, it is always present as contact person in *Microsoft Outlook*.

I compared two people that were present in *Outlook*, of which (in *Skype*) one was sorted by its first name and one by its family name. I checked whether there were mistakes in the name fields in *Outlook*, but this seemed not to be the case.

Comment: See also [this Skype page](http://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/10307319-add-option-to-specify-how-outlook-contacts-are-dis).